# How to add a new column to data frame based on two columns of other data frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames `df_data` and `df_node_labels`:

```
df_data =

    nodeId   field1
    1        abc
    2        def
    3        fed
    4        kfl

df_node_labels =
    srcId   srcLabel    dstId    dstLabel
    1       AAA         2        BBB
    2       BBB         4        FFF
    4       FFF         3        CCC
```

I want to add a column `label` to `df_data`. The values of `label` should be taken from `srcLabel` and `dstLabel`:

This is how I tried to grab label information:

```
var df = df_data.join(df_node_labels.select("srcId","srcLabel"),col("nodeId")===col("srcId"),"left")
df = df.join(df_node_labels.select("dstId","dstLabel"),col("nodeId")===col("dstId"),"left")
```

However, this creates two columns `srcLabel` and `dstLabel` in `df`, while I want to get just one column `label`.

This is the expected result:

```
df =
        nodeId   field1   label
        1        abc      AAA
        2        def      BBB
        3        fed      CCC
        4        kfl      FFF
```

**Update:**

I can do it this way, but in my opinion it is a long way to do a simple thing:

```
df = df.withColumn("label", when(col("srcLabel") =!= "", col("srcLabel")).otherwise(col("dstLabel"))).drop("srcLabel").drop("dstLabel")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a unique data from `df_node_labels` as a `finalDF` in below and perform a `join` operation which will give you an expected result.

```
val finalDF = df_node_labels.select($"srcId".as("nodeId"), $"srcLabel".as("label"))
  .union(
    df_node_labels.select($"dstId".as("nodeId"), $"dstLabel".as("label"))
  ).dropDuplicates()


df_data.join(finalDF, Seq("nodeId"), "left")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------+------+-----+
|nodeId|field1|label|
+------+------+-----+
|1     |abc   |AAA  |
|2     |def   |BBB  |
|3     |fed   |CCC  |
|4     |kfl   |FFF  |
+------+------+-----+
```

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Interestingly, node labels dataframe suggest that it may have different labels if a node is a `src` or a `dst`.  Otherwise, that structure does not really makes sense.

Comment: @MichelLemay: What do you mean? The issue was that `nodeId` does not always belong to `srcId`, and it should be also searched in `dstId` column.

Comment: I noticed that you have (srcId, srcLabel) and (dstId, dstLabel) with possible sharing of nodeIds between srcId and dstId. Therefore, doing the union and removing duplicates like shown in the answer might introduce issues if you have different labels for the same nodeId.

Comment: @MichelLemay: But `srcLabel` always correspond to `dstLabel` if `srcId` is the same as `dstId`.

Comment: @ScalaBoy yes but the data structure permits otherwise and it's probably a bad design IMHO. What if you have other vertex (node) metadata?  It could definitly become a pain to keep in sync in an evolving large data table.